# why is algolia numericmenu disabled (Algolia with React.js)

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch

I want to add algolia numeric menu Refinement filters and I added them successfully but when they show up on the web they are disabled
[image]

here is the code

```
               <NumericMenu
                    attribute="buyItNowPrice"
                    items={[
                      { label: '<= $10', end: 10 },
                      { label: '$10 - $100', start: 10, end: 100 },
                      { label: '$100 - $500', start: 100, end: 250 },
                      { label: '>= $500', start: 500 },
                    ]}
                  />
```

as you can see in the image above they automatically add an "ALL" Radio button. the Strange thing is The Refinements work because when I use the browser's inspect tools to enable the radio buttons work fine and I get accurate results. OR is possible to enable the HTML-disabled input using CSS

Comment: couldnt exactly replicate ur scenario. but when there are no hits that fall into the start and end it dsables. try https://codesandbox.io/s/numericmenu-jrs2ph and type "cmgches" in the search then try to select some radiobuttons

Comment: did u manage to fix it